# Linking error while trying to integrate FOMD application with mine

Tags: iphone, fmod, linker-errors

i am trying to use FMOD example application "dsp_effectperspeaker" in my application. But i m getting error

```
  dyld: Library not loaded: @loader_path/../Frameworks/libfmodex.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/asimahmed/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications/AF942B1F-A2CB-42D7-B878-47F3F7D51CAF/ChannelSound.app/ChannelSound
  Reason: image not found
```

i googled and found this http://brockwoolf.com/blog/how-to-use-dynamic-libraries-in-xcode-31-using-fmod

but error is still there.

Usman

Comment: fixed it at-last, don't know how, just change targets build setting.

Answer (score 1):

When developing for the iPhone you should be linking against the FMOD static libs, not any dylibs, as dynamic linking is prohibited for iPhone apps.

Also note that the only FMOD dylibs are those for the Mac, which contain totally different OS code compared with the proper iPhone static libs.

Answer (score 0):

This tutotual descibe how to include the libraries:
http://www.sundh.com/blog/2011/08/set-up-fmod-for-iphone-in-xcode/